# Distribution and Analytical solution of a GBM with stochastic interest rate?

Tags: brownian-motion, vasicek

We model the exchange rate $S_t$ with a geometric Brownian motion and the USD and EUR interest rates $r_u$ and $r_e$ each according to the Vasicek model. Under the domestic equivalent martingale measure $Q$, our model with three state variables can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dS_t}{S_t} &=& (r_t^u - r_t^e)dt + \sigma_S dW_t^S \\
dr_t^u &=& \kappa_u(\theta_u - r_t^u)dt + \sigma_d dW_t^u \\
dr_t^e &=& \kappa_e(\theta_e - r_t^e) dt + \sigma_e dW_t^e
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\kappa_u$ and $\kappa_e$ are the mean reversion rates, $\theta_u$ and $\theta_e$ are the long-term means, $\sigma_S$, $\sigma_u$, and $\sigma_e$ are the instantaneous volatilities, and $W_t^S$, $W_t^u$, and $W_t^e$ are the Brownian motions linked by the correlation matrix
\begin{eqnarray*}
\rho = \left(\begin{array}{cc c}
   1 & \rho_{Su} & \rho_{Se}  \\
   - &1& \rho_{ue} \\
   - & - & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

I am looking for the distribution of $S_t$. I know that the analytical solution of $S_t$ takes the following form, of course, if I am right:

\begin{eqnarray*}
S_t = S_l \exp\Big\{ \int_{l}^{t}\Big((r_y^u - r_y^e) - \frac{\sigma_S^2}{2}\Big)dy + \sigma_S W_{t-l}^S \Big\},
\end{eqnarray*}

I wonder if $S_t$ is normally distributed? If so, how I can find the expectation and variance. The most difficulty goes for the integral part.

Thank you in advance for any help you guys can provide me.

Comment: Under HW dynamics the time integral of the rate is normally distributed. A linear combination of normal random variables is also normal. So $S_t$ should be a lognormal R.V. as in the deterministic case. For mean and variance you'll need to find the closed form mean and variances of the rate integrals, look up Brigo's book on rates.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by HW? since I am new in finance, I can not realize some abbreviations.

Comment: So, there is proof letting me know what the distribution of time integral of rate is?

Comment: Yes, HW is hull white. You can derive it yourself or look at Interest rates modeling by Brigo. As far as I remember it involves a double integral and Fubini's theorem to interchange the limits. Substitute the closed form expression of $r_t$ in the integral and work from there.

Comment: Thank you, my friend.